# Laravel converting date format before saving in database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

i am using Laravel mutator, here is how my date format is showing in view,

> 20/03/04

i want to convert it to

> 20-03-04

format before saving,
To do that on one column i tried following code in my model,

```
public function setdobAttribute($input)
{
  $d= date_create_from_format('d/m/Y',$input);
    $this->attributes['dob'] = $d->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

it's working fine for one column, but i want to apply same function on multiple columns, how can i achieve that, i also tried;

```
protected $casts = [
    'dob'  => 'date:Y-m-d',
    'work_date' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:00',
];
```

but it's not working.
**Error: Unexpected data found. Unexpected data found. Data missing**

Comment: $date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($oldTime));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want this as a function

```
function changedateformat($origDate)
{
  $date = str_replace('/', '-', $origDate );
  $newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($date));
  return $newDate;
}
```

whenever you need conversion,call the function using `res = changedateformat($data);`

Comment: how to do it on multiple columns

Answer (score 0):

```
public function setDateAttribute( $value ) {
  $this->attributes['date'] = (new Carbon($value))->format('d/m/y');
}
```

The setDateAttribute is always in the format set[ColumnName]Attribute, using CamelCase. The date in the $this->attributes['date'] part must also match your actual column name in the table.

When you create or update a record in your database, the format will automatically be changed by the function above.

Note: You may need to add the use Carbon\Carbon statement to the top of your Model to use the Carbon library.

Take a look at other examples here.

UPDATE

Optionally, you can define a format for `date` columns using:

```
protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d';
```

I guess you can override `setAttribute` method like:

```
public function setAttribute($key, $value){
    if(in_array($key, 'abstract_keys')){
        $this->attributes[$key] = !!$value;
    }
    else{
        parent::setAttribute($key, $value);
    }
}
```

Same would go for `getAttribute`.

Comment: as mentioned it is already working, but i want to apply same function on multiple columns without repeating code.

Comment: can you set your example code for, for example DOB and startDate column.